# How can I profile my Blazor (server side) app?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have read [ASP.NET Core Blazor performance best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0#main) (which is super helpful). But now I'm on to trying to figure out where my hot spots are. And some (all?) of this will almost certainly be database (Entity Framework) access.

So, are there any tools out there that work best with Blazor. I'm server side Blazor so the browser <kbd>F12</kbd> profiling will likely be of no help. I have dotTrace, but it's not that helpful on database profiling.

And while step 1 is profiling on my dev system, the real world profiling is running my app on Azure (App server & SQL Database) and profiling it there.

And then load testing it on Azure.
So what is normally used?